# How to create a checkpoint for DeltaLake in Azure Databricks for past data with Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I don't know how to create a checkpoint for DeltaLake in Azure Databricks for a past version.

I tried to access the "DeltaLog" object without success to execute that:

```
DeltaLog.forTable(spark,dataPath).checkpoint()
```

I would like to create checkpoints for an older version.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to create a checkpoint for a past version?

Comment: Yes, I can. The problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561637/i-receive-the-error-cannot-time-travel-delta-table-to-version-x-whereas-i-can/66850064#66850064. I want to retrieve older versions that were removed.